# Is over provisioning working as expected on my Samsung SSD after reinstalling Windows 10 update 2004?

Tags: ssd, windows-10-v2004

After I reinstalled Windows 10 update 2004, I restarted the system see something strange. After the C partition is system restored the reserved parition, it was reconfigured to 10% of SSD before install OS.

Now in Samsung Magician I see something that seems strange to me regarding over provisioning. If I choose manual I can add more over provisioning at C partition at end. If I choose other drive there all as expected.

Question is if it worked as expected or I need reinstall the OS and after install create over provisioning for it work as normal; this is the way system restore reserved the partition to be at the end.

If it works and not be worried about it. Or this can work not as expected and better do all how need. And how I remembered older versions of Windows worked was to always create system reserved spaces at start at of disk, and C was always end partition. This why it confuse me.

[image]
[image]
[image]